# How to delete all files under a directory for Unity Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

How can I delete all files under a directory? Looks like listAll() does not exist for Unity package.
Is the only option is by saving the names for all the files somewhere and delete them one by one?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you just create a `StorageReference` at the location that you want to delete and then run `DeleteAsync()` on that location?

Comment: @Alex Firebase doesn't allow deleting directories as far as I know.